# Django - converting object to queryset without querying database

Tags: django, orm

It often happens in my Django code that I have to make some operations with an object and then pass it on to other function in a form of a queryset. For now, I take the id of the object and query the database, which seems like junk code since I already have all data.

Better illustrated by an example:

```
obj = MyModelSerializer(data)
obj.save()
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id = obj.id).values() # queries db just to get a queryset representation of a single object
return render(request, 'test.html', {'qs': qs})
```

Is there any better way to overwrite this code? Or it is perfectly ok ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `test.html` template needs a QuerySet you're code is fine the way it is. Refetching the data is inefficient, but there is no documented way to populate a QuerySet except through the database.

You don't give an example `test.html` but in many cases you could skip the QuerySet and pass a list instead, for example:

```
obj = MyModelSerializer(data)
obj.save()
return render(request, 'test.html', {'qs': [obj]})
```

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer, Matt. But the problem is that I really need a QUERY object )

Comment: Your welcome, Edgar. What methods does the template requires from the QuerySet, perhaps there is a way to make another collection work in place of the QuerySet.